# How long will it take for my heat to work after refilling antifreeze?

Tags: jeep, heater, liberty, antifreeze

Two days ago the heat in our 2011 Jeep Liberty was working fine. Yesterday my wife said the heat wasn't working, it was blowing air but it wasn't warm. I looked online and it was suggested that the first thing to do was to check the antifreeze levels. They were basically empty.

I refilled it and had it running for about 10 min before I went to work and it took about 10 min to get to work. It wasn't warm yet but I also don't know what it felt like before adding antifreeze.

How long should it take for there to be heat again if the problem was the lack of antifreeze? If it never heats up, what could be the problem?

Comment: Did you fill and bleed the system properly so you have removed all the air bubbles? If you did not, then a large air bubble can cause an airlock which means you still get no heat...

Comment: And when bleeding your cooling system the heat selector should be set to full hot.

Comment: I filled and bled the system. I did think about blend door and noticed on the way home clicking when I switched between hot and cold. After inspection my actuator was malfunctioning and I bought a new one and will need to get it calibrated. I currently have the actuator removed and the blend door fixed on hot. Thank you for your responses.

Answer (score 1):

The heat should be there as soon as your engine gets warm, however long that takes. In an average car (is there such a think), I'd guessedamate that to be in the 3-5 minute range once the vehicle has started moving, or about 10 minutes if it's just idling (this also depends on how cold it is outside ... cold-cold, it'll take longer ... just chilly, not near as long). You should be able to look at the engine temperature gauge on the dash (if the Liberty is so equipped). When it gets up to temperature (usually the middle of the gauge for most vehicles), the air out of your vents should be hot at that point too.

If it never heats up, there are two things which come to mind. First, the heater core may be plugged. You can test the two hoses going into the passenger compartment from the engine itself. If both of these are hot when the fan blower is not blowing, the heater core is most likely in good shape. Secondly, if the thermostat is stuck in the open position. Usually, though, once the engine heats up, if the thermostat is stuck open, the air will be lukewarm. If the thermostat is stuck open, it would take the engine a long time to heat up (not just the heater core).

**EDIT:** I would like to add, what Solar Mike put in comments is correct as well. You need to double check to ensure there's no air in the system. If there's an air pocket in the wrong place, this could cause the heater core not to get warm, either.